# How to remove quickblox account user name from user list?

Tags: android, quickblox, quickblox-android

Basically I am retrieving QBUser list from quickblox server and I don't want Admin(application registered - account owner) name to be listed as QBUser.

**Example :**

I signup quickblox with name "A" to register "xyz" application.
Afterwards I add certain users ("B","C","D") to application "xyz".

Now when I request user list API for "xyz" application I want only ("B","C","D") in response, but the issue is user list contains all users ("A","B","C","D").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt there's a query to exempt a particular user from the query but you can handle that in your code when the user list is returned.

```
QBPagedRequestBuilder pagedRequestBuilder = new QBPagedRequestBuilder();
pagedRequestBuilder.setPage(1);
pagedRequestBuilder.setPerPage(50);

QBUsers.getUsers(pagedRequestBuilder, new QBEntityCallback<ArrayList<QBUser>>() {

@Override
public void onSuccess(ArrayList<QBUser> users, Bundle params) {

    for(QBUser user: users){
       if(user.getFullName().equals("A"))
           users.remove(user);
    }

    //go ahead to use users list without A

}

@Override
public void onError(QBResponseException errors) {

}
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I end up doing this same.